# Rename [torment-ton] to [torment-tides-of-numenera]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

One of our tags is [torment-ton](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torment-ton). Can we have that renamed to [torment-tides-of-numenera](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torment-tides-of-numenera), the full name? I'm not sure why it was abbreviated in the first place, since it is 25 characters.

Comment: IIRC, the change that allowed tags to be up to 35 characters happened in August, and that tag is a bit older than that, so that's probably why it was abbreviated at first.

Comment: @MageXy But the full name is 25 characters, which would have fit before the tag length extension.

Comment: Welp then I don't know. Maybe the creator though it looked a *ton* more stylish? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure can! I've done that for you. :)